# The broadcast frequency of a base station can be change?

Tags: gsm, cellular-network, software-defined-radio

I am scanning the frequencies of BTSs (Base station) around me with my RTL-SDR device. I found a few. For example the frequency of one was 958.4 MHz. After three days later I scanned again but this time it disappeared. There was no BTS with frequency 958.4MHz instead I found frequencies completely different.

Can the frequency of the base station change? Or how did I get a completely different result from the scan I made three days ago.

Comment: Yes, that can, as you observed. What is your question?

Comment: Is this normal? Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: normal. Base stations switch on and off to save energy in low-demand situations, and frequencies are usually licensed per larger areas than cells, so frequency changes can happen.